# Urn draws with replacement problem: number of drawn white balls till we draw black ball for the k-th time

Tags: probability

In the urn we have a white, b red and c black balls. We draw with replacement. Calculate the expected number of white balls, which are drawn until we drew black ball for the k-th time.

My solution:
The expected number of draws till be draw black ball for the k-th time is:
$$\left(\frac{a+b+c}{c} \right)^k$$ That should be correct? I don't really know how to continue.

The below is obviously wrong due to comments.
In the sequence of turns there are

$$\left( \frac{a+b+c}{c} \right)^k-k$$

possibilities to draw white or red. Therefore

$$\frac{b}{a+b+c}\left(\left(\frac{a+b+c}{c} \right)^k-k \right)$$

of them are white.
Is my solution correct?

Comment: As a side note:  it's at least an informal convention to use variable names that match the colors.  I assumed that $b$ was the number of black balls, for instance.  Here, the red balls are irrelevant and can be ignored, I'd just use $w,b$ for the white and black balls.  makes it easier to read.

Comment: I suggest:  start with $k=1$.  Work recursively  from there.

Comment: My first comment had an error, so I deleted it.  Half of it was correct, though:  if $a=0$ the answer here is clearly $0$, as you'll never draw white.  Yet your formula does not yield $0$ in that case.

Comment: For another illustration that the formula can't be right, suppose $b=0$, so there are no red balls.  That clearly has no effect on the number of white balls chosen before you see however many blacks, yet the formula yields $0$ in this case.

Comment: Please show all of your work, directly in the posted question, (not the comments) in very clear detail.  That is, please clarify how you reached each conclusion in your posted question.

Comment: For what it's worth, virtually no MathSE posted question that I have seen (from me or anyone else) that followed 
[this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236) 
has been downvoted. Instead, such questions are almost always upvoted, with 
MathSE reviewers going out of their way to try to answer the question.

Comment: Note:  while I don't think this is the best method, you can do it along these lines.  Your big mistake is in the first line.  The expected number of draws until you get the first black ball is indeed, $\frac {a+b+c}c$.  But, after that, the expected number is *linear* in $k$, hence additive, not multiplicative as you have suggested.

Comment: You can get properly sized parentheses (and other paired delimiters) that adjust to the size of their content by preceding them with `\left` and `\right`.

Answer (score 0):

$\textbf{Hint}$

Following lulu's advice to use friendly nomenclature for symbols, and realising that the red balls are irrelevant,

Let $w$ = # of white balls, $b$ = # of black balls, $n = w+b$, then

P(black) $=p = \dfrac{b}{n},\;\;$ P(white) $=1-p = q$

The earliest the $k_{th}$ black could come would be at position # $k$ in the queue with no white preceding it, then at  # $(k+1)$ with one white preceding it, and so on upto all $w$ whites preceding it

Thus P(expected # of whites preceding # $k_{th}$ ball)

$= \dfrac{(k-1)!}{(k-1)!0!}q^0p^k*0 + \dfrac{k!}{(k-1)!1!}q^1p^k*1 +...$
(If you prefer, you could use binomial coefficirnts rather than permutations)

You should be able to continue from here, and also condense the formula ?

> Letting $j$ be the counter for the number of whites before the $k_{th}$ black, the expected # of whites before the $k_{th}$ black
>  $$ =\sum_{j=0}^w \binom{k+j-1}{j}q^jp^k*j$$

Answer (score 0):

To summarize the discussion in the comments:

The red balls are irrelevant, so let's ignore them.  And let's use $W,B$ for the number of white and black balls respectively.

Let $E_k$ denote the answer we seek, for a given $k$.

We first solve the case $k=1$. Considering the result of the first draw, we have $$E_1=\frac B{W+B}\times 0+\frac W{W+B}\times (1+E_1)\implies E_1=\frac WB$$

But it is clear that $E_k=E_{k-1}+E_1$ so we have $$\boxed {E_k=\frac {kW}B}$$

Sanity Checks:  if $W=0$ this vanishes, as it must.  If $B=0$ this is infinite, as again it must be.  Also, it's easy to see that replacing $(W,B)$ by $(nW, nB)$ has no effect on the expectation, and the formula reflects that.

As mentioned in the comments, the idea behind your approach is fine, though you get the initial expectation wrong.  Specifically, the expectation is additive in $k$, not multiplicative as you have written.  Once you correct this, you should be able to make your computation go through.  Specifically:  We expect it to take $\frac {B+W}B=1+\frac WB$ draws to see the first black ball, hence $$k\times \left( 1+\frac WB\right)=k+\frac {kW}B$$ draws to see the $k^{th}$, and all but $k$ of those are White.